# Web Extension (Браузерное расширению)

Tags: javascript, база-данных, браузер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли к своему расширению подключить базу данных, для выполнения запросов, через JS, или Web Extension работает только с PHP? Сейчас на любой код подключения к базе данных (JS, PHP) браузер начинает ругаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое, что можно сделать, развернуть промежуточный сервер на ноде(rest апи) и через ajax передавать данные с бд в экстет

Кстати, после того, как гогол запретил в обфускаторы, самое время создавать на ноде+фрамеворк интерфейс пользовательский и вырезать всё возможное с экстета на серверную часть, а в экстете оставлять кода по необходимости\мелочи в минифае\углифае или вообще eval(что не есть гуд практик и чуть ли не банится гоглом)

Comment: а можно как то отправить запрос от Web Extension  (расширения) в бд?

Comment: @GetTM нужно от базы данных отталкиваться